# SQL new column with boolean value based on column entry

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
columnA     | columnB     | columnC
-----------------------------------
1           |10           |88
2           |10           |88
3           |10           |88
1           |20           |66
2           |20           |66
3           |20           |66
1           |30           |77
2           |30           |77
```

I want to create a new column for each unique entry in column C with boolean value whether it exists, in this way:

```
columnA     | columnB   | column88 | column66 | column77 
---------------------------------------------------------
1           |10         |True      |True      |True
2           |20         |True      |True      |True
3           |30         |True      |True      |False
```

How can I achieve such a table?

Comment: I don't understand the output. Why don't you have a row for e.g. [1 - 20]? Why does COLUMN66 (the first row in output table) have TRUE as output when there's no [1 - 10] row for 66 in the original table?

Comment: You will need to decide how to represent True/False in your model, e.g. Y/N or 0/1, as there is no Boolean data type in Oracle SQL.

Comment: How do you get the values for `columnB` in your output? If `columnA` is `1` then `columnB` could be `10`, `20` or `30` and there is no obvious logic why you should have the pairings `1, 10`, `2, 20`, `3, 30` and not `1, 30` or `2, 10` etc.

Comment: columnB always have the same values if the values of column c are the same.

Comment: @honeymoon They do not in your example.

Comment: Don't understand, 10=88, 20=66, 30=77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation`

```
select colA, colB, 
       max(case when colC=88 then 'True' else 'False' end) as col88,
       max(case when colC=66 then 'True' else 'False' end) as col66,
       max(case when colC=77 then 'True' else 'False' end) as col77
from tablename
group by colA, colB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(1)
  FOR colC IN (
    88 AS col88,
    77 AS col77,
    66 AS col66
  )
)
ORDER BY colA, colB
```

*(Oracle SQL does not have a boolean data type so you need to use something else to represent `True` and `False`. PL/SQL does but you can't use it in SQL.)*

Which, for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( colA, colB, colC ) AS
SELECT 1, 10, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 20, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 20, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 30, 66 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 30, 66 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> COLA | COLB | COL88 | COL77 | COL66
> ---: | ---: | ----: | ----: | ----:
>    1 |   10 |     1 |  null |  null
>    1 |   20 |  null |     1 |  null
>    1 |   30 |  null |  null |     1
>    2 |   10 |     1 |  null |  null
>    2 |   20 |  null |     1 |  null
>    2 |   30 |  null |  null |     1
>    3 |   10 |     1 |  null |  null
>    3 |   20 |  null |     1 |  null
> ```

*(`1` represents true and `NULL` represents false. If you want to change it to `0` then you can change `SELECT *` to a list of columns and use `COALESCE( col88, 0 ) AS coll88` to translate the `NULL` values.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad557a48807d83b0fa5c6efbe6a74c83)*

---

From comments:

> columnB always have the same values if the values of column c are the same.

If the sample data is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( colA, colB, colC ) AS
SELECT 1, 10, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 30, 77 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, 66 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 66 FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> COLA | COLB | COL88 | COL77 | COL66
> ---: | ---: | ----: | ----: | ----:
>    1 |   10 |     1 |     1 |     1
>    2 |   20 |     1 |     1 |     1
>    3 |   30 |     1 |     1 |  null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a3e0f7c6096bfa6e1bdf6b5a18818c3)*